# How to dynamically set the selected radio button with the controller in JavaScript - Salesforce

Tags: javascript, radio-button, salesforce

I have a community page designed like a wizard step-by-step interface. I have to keep the user-selected radio button value selected when the user navigates between pages. But in my code, the value is saved in the attribute but not able to set the radio selected. Any help appreciated.

```
<tbody><aura:iteration items="{!v.publicAttributes.contactRecords}" var="row">                     
<tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                         <td data-label="" scope="row">                                                        <ui:inputRadio aura:id="{!row.Id}" name="options"  text="{!row.Id}" change="{!c.onRadio}" value="" />                          </td>                         
                         <td data-label="FirstName">                               
                         <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!row.FirstName}">{!row.FirstName}</div>                         </td>  <td data-label="LastName">                               <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!row.LastName}">{!row.LastName}</div>                         </td>                         
                         <td data-label="Email">                               
                         <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!row.Email}">{!row.Email}</div>                         </td>                         
                         <td data-label="Phone">                               
                         <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!row.Phone}">{!row.Phone}</div>                         </td>                     
                         </tr>                 
                         </aura:iteration>             
                         </tbody>
```

```
onRadio: function(component, event) {
         var selected = event.getSource().get("v.value");
         var seltext = event.getSource().get("v.text");     
          console.log("selectedval" + selected);
          console.log("seltext" + seltext);                
            var contact = component.get("v.publicAttributes").contactRecord;   
            var contactList = publicAttributes.contactRecords;
            var found = contactList.find(e => e.Id === seltext);
            console.log(found);
            component.set("v.publicAttributes.contactRecord.FirstName",found["FirstName"]);
            component.set("v.publicAttributes.contactRecord.LastName",found["LastName"]);
            component.set("v.publicAttributes.contactRecord.Email",found["Email"]);
            component.set("v.publicAttributes.contactRecord.Phone",found["Phone"]);     
            
            var elem = event.getSource();
            var selected = elem.get("v.text");
            component.set("v.publicAttributes.selectedRadioSurveyContact", selected);   
            console.log("Radiocheck" + component.get("v.publicAttributes.selectedRadioSurveyContact"));
     },
```

```
init: function (component, event, helper) { 
 var publicAttributes = component.get("v.publicAttributes");  
var contactRecord = component.get("v.publicAttributes").contactRecord;   
var contactList = publicAttributes.contactRecords;
var selectedContact = component.get("v.publicAttributes").selectedRadioContact;
if(selectedContact != "")
{
//When user come backs to this page
//Here i have to set the radio button selected what the user selected before
//selectedContact have the contact.Id value

document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name="options"][value="${selectedContact }"]').checked = true;

 //the above code didn't work //?????? any help # 
}
}
```

document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name="options"][value="${selectedContact }"]').checked = true;

This didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding If

```
<ui:inputRadio aura:id="{!row.Id}" name="options"  text="{!row.Id}" change="{!c.onRadio}" value="{!if(row.Id == v.publicAttributes.selectedRadioContact, true, false)}" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).